# How to change on y-axis the sequence of my categorical column?

Tags: python, plot

I want to change the sequence of my categorical column. I used stripplot because I want to plot one categorial column named "chol" and one integer named "age".

The "chol"  can take 3 different inputs "low", "boardline" and "high". When I wrote the code in the highest level of my plot was the "borderline"" and then the "high" and then the "low". I believe that Python take them with alphabetical sequence. How to put in the highest level on the plot "high", then "borderline"" and then"lower"?

```
sns.stripplot(x="age", y="chol", data=df)
```

[image: Plot described]

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow! Could you please post an example dataset to make it easier for us to help you.

Comment: I feel like you might want to use a histogram with the actual numbers and adjust the axis to the labels. Also, I believe you mean "borderline", not "boardline"

Answer (score 1):

With order can change the sequence that appears your plot.

```
  sns.stripplot(x="chol", y="age",order=["low","boarfline","High"],data=df)
```